# How to capture the AutoCompleteTextView arrow click event

Tags: java, android, events, drop-down-menu, autocompletetextview

[image: Arrow]

How do I ***capture*** the click on the `AutoCompleteTextView` arrow.

`OnClick` works for the rest of the component, but it doesn't work when you specifically click the arrow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It took a while, but I found the solution.

The event is in the parent of the AutoCompleteTextView.

XML:

[XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGfER.png)

Solution:

```
public com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout txtGleba;
```

...

```
txtGleba = findViewById(R.id.txtGleba);
    txtGleba.setEndIconOnClickListener  (new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });
```

Comment: If I use `setEndIconOnClickListener`, the drop down menu is not longer works (the arrow icon doesn't rotate and the menu is not shown).